# Convergence of the Euler product

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Suppose that the Riemann Hypothesis is true. It is well known that then the Dirichlet series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$ converges in the half-plane ${\rm {Re}}\, s>\frac{1}{2}$.

Does the convergence hold (in some sense) if the sum is replaced by the Euler product $$\prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)?$$

Comment: The problem is that $\prod_p(1-\frac{1}{p^s})$ is not absolutely convergent (in other words $\prod_p(1+\frac{1}{p^s})$ is not convergent) even for $s=1$. So equating it to the Dirichlet series for $s\le 1$ is invalid.

Comment: Doesn't $\prod_p(1-1/p)$ converge for $s=1$?

Comment: @PITTALUGA $\prod_p(1-1/p^s)$ converges to 0 for $0<s<1$. In the jargon, it "diverges" to 0. But, for example, $\sum_1^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{0.9}}\approx-0.11$.

Comment: @almagest: You are right, for $s\leq 1$ the product diverges to zero. However, is this a typical behaviour for the whole strip ${\rm{Re}}\,s\in(1/2, 1)$? Does the product converge on a subarea of the strip? (By the way, for $s=1$ the limit coincides with the sum of the series!)

Comment: The answer is negative, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63714/is-the-euler-product-formula-always-divergent-for-0res1).